# Windows App Certification Kit - "did not detect any new application" , ClickOnce

Tags: windows-8, windows-store, wack

I have a Windows Desktop App ( WPF + c++ ).

I have just made a ClickOnce installer. I built it on Windows 7, but I want to certify the App for the Windows Store, so I'm running the Windows App Certification kit on Windows 8.

The installer works fine, it installs my application and puts an icon on Windows 8 start screen. My Application runs fine. I then uninstalled it ready to run the certification.

When I try to Certify it, the Application Compatibility Kit fails to install it ( a couple of windows flash open and closed SO fast I can't read them, I DON'T experience the installer dialog which would normally require some interaction from me).

Then the kit pops a dialog:

> The Windows App Certification Kit did not detect any new applications
>   as a result of your installation. testing cannot continue unless an
>   application is successfully installed).

Previously a had a MSI installer that did seem to work with the compatibility kit (the app failed certification, but for legitimate reasons). Now I can't get the compatibility kit to even install my ClickOnce application. How can I certify my desktop app?

**Edit** Desktop apps are indeed possible in the store. See this. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh749939.aspx

Comment: I have no idea of why this was voted down. I need help with this too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ClickOnce applications are not eligible for Windows 7 and Windows 8 Software Logo program.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowscompatibility/thread/f10242cb-39f1-4f5e-ac1f-e55a6c722a6b